# Angular FormControl not detecting changes made by input directive

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I have an directive (which I cannot take credit for) that only allows the user to input whole non-negative numbers.  It works fine, but the problem is the `formcontrol` tied to the `matInput` field is not picking up the changes. Thank you in advance for any suggestions on solving this.

Here is the directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[numeric]"
})
export class NumericDirective {
  @Input("decimals") decimals: number = 0;
  @Input("negative") negative: number = 0;
  @Input("separator") separator: string = ".";

  private checkAllowNegative(value: string) {
    if (this.decimals <= 0) {
      return String(value).match(new RegExp(/^-?\d+$/));
    } else {
      var regExpString =
        "^-?\\s*((\\d+(\\"+ this.separator +"\\d{0," +
        this.decimals +
        "})?)|((\\d*(\\"+ this.separator +"\\d{1," +
        this.decimals +
        "}))))\\s*$";
      return String(value).match(new RegExp(regExpString));
    }
  }

  private check(value: string) {
    if (this.decimals <= 0) {
      return String(value).match(new RegExp(/^\d+$/));
    } else {
      var regExpString =
        "^\\s*((\\d+(\\"+ this.separator +"\\d{0," +
        this.decimals +
        "})?)|((\\d*(\\"+ this.separator +"\\d{1," +
        this.decimals +
        "}))))\\s*$";
      return String(value).match(new RegExp(regExpString));
    }
  }

  private run(oldValue: any) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let currentValue: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      let allowNegative = this.negative > 0 ? true : false;

      console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value)
      
      console.log(oldValue)
      if (allowNegative) {
        if (
          !["", "-"].includes(currentValue) &&
          !this.checkAllowNegative(currentValue)
        ) {
          this.el.nativeElement.value = oldValue;
        }
      } else {
        if (currentValue !== "" && !this.check(currentValue)) {
          this.el.nativeElement.value = oldValue;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.run(this.el.nativeElement.value);
  }

  @HostListener("paste", ["$event"])
  onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
    this.run(this.el.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

This the html for the input:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="field">
                <mat-label>Select Number Of Item(s) to {{data.action | titlecase}}</mat-label>
                <input matInput numeric type="number" formControlName="quantity"
                    [placeholder]="'Available Quantity ' + data.item.quantity">
                <div
                    *ngIf="this.actionFormGroup.get('quantity').invalid && (this.actionFormGroup.get('quantity').dirty || this.actionFormGroup.get('quantity').touched)">
                    <div *ngIf="this.actionFormGroup.get('quantity').errors.max">
                        <mat-error>
                            Exceeded Item Quantity
                        </mat-error>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngIf="this.actionFormGroup.get('quantity').errors.min">
                        <mat-error>
                            Minimum Quantity of 1 Required
                        </mat-error>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-form-field>
```

and here is the form control declaration:

```
  setFormGroup(): void {
this.actionFormGroup = new FormGroup({
  quantity: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(this.data.item.quantity), Validators.pattern('^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$')]),
  destination: new FormControl(this.getDestination(), Validators.required)
});
if (this.data.item.quantity === 1) {
  this.actionFormGroup.get("quantity")!.setValue(1);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NgControl` to inject this `FormControl` into your `directive` like this:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef,
    @Optional() @Host() private ngControl: NgControl) {
  }
```

and use it to update value of input

```
...
if (!['', '-'].includes(currentValue) &&
    !this.checkAllowNegative(currentValue)) {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.ngControl.control.setValue(oldValue);
    } else {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = oldValue;
    }
}
...
```

and here also (do it for any other similar places in your directive)

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.ngControl) {
      this.run(this.ngControl.control.value);
    } else {
      this.run(this.el.nativeElement.value);
    }
  }
```